# Implementing Custom Email Verification and Password Reset Pages in Flutter Mobile App without Keycloak Web Pages

Tags: flutter, keycloak

We have been using Keycloak as the Identity Provider for our web application, where users receive an email after signing up to verify their email and set their password using Keycloak's built-in actions (**VERIFY_EMAIL**, **RESET_PASSWORD**). This is achieved through a redirect to Keycloak provided page for password reset.

Now, we are transitioning our platform to a native Flutter mobile app and want to implement the email verification and password reset pages as native widgets within the app. We want to avoid using WebViews for this purpose. Ideally, we would like to provide a (deep) link within the email, which redirects the user to the corresponding app widget or a download page for the app.

We considered implementing custom SPIs combined with Keycloak REST APIs for the required actions, but after reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512044/obtain-action-token-reset-password-with-keycloak-admin-api) discussion, we became concerned about possible vulnerabilities associated with this approach.

Is there a secure method to bypass Keycloak's web pages and implement custom flow pages within our mobile app while ensuring the necessary security measures?